# Anyone remember a movie where a man is hunting a killer and a scientist gives him an arm band that resurrects the wearer?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I am trying hard to remember a movie, it was on the early Sci-Fi channel but I'm not sure if it was made by Sci-Fi (actually, I think it was a good movie). I've been searching Google and Scy-Fy but no luck. It is pretty old I think.

The story involved a man hunting for a killer and a scientist with a device for bringing the wearer back to life. I forget most of the story unfortunately but I do remember something bad happened, of course. I think the man's wife was killed by someone and this scientist knew the person. In his search for the killer the man finds the scientist, who I think actually dies pretty soon afterward, that gives the man an arm band (?) that somehow detected when the wearer died and injected them with something to bring them back to life so he could keep hunting the killer.  I remember the scientist saying a line like "you must fight like someone who isn't afraid of death".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The description you gave reminds me of the movie *Deep Red*.
[The description on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109589/)  doesn't match yours but I believe this might be the movie you are thinking of. I'll see if I can find more and add to it.

Comment: Wow, that was a tough one to find. Okay, I checked out the movie online. That wasn't it unfortunately. Deep Red was interesting for what was obviously a pretty low budget film. It struck me as somewhat original for that time period though.  I'll keep looking for my movie. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like *Last Lives* (1997):

> A telepathic terrorist from a parallel universe kidnaps a woman on her wedding day. The groom tracks them down after receiving assistance from the inventor of a life restoring bracelet. The bride was considered the terrorists telepathic life partner.
>
> — [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119499/plotsummary)
>
> ---
>
> A man must wage a battle against time, space, and his own mortality to rescue his wife-to-be in this sci-fi drama. Malakai (Billy Wirth) is a criminal from an alternate universe who has a psychic link with a woman on Earth named Adrienne (Jennifer Rubin). Adrienne, however, knows nothing about this, and when Malakai comes to Earth and kidnaps her on her wedding day in a hale of bullets, it comes as a highly unpleasant surprise. Merkhan (Judge Reinhold), a scientist who has done research of Malakai's parallel world, has invented a special bracelet that will allow the wearer to come back to life if killed by an alien like Malakai; armed with Markhan's secret weapon, Aaron (C. Thomas Howell), Adrienne's fiancé, sets out to find and rescue the woman he loves.
>
> — [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/last_lives/)